# Exibir um vídeo do Youtube pelo videoView através do Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, url, xamarin, vídeo

Estou precisando exibir um vídeo por uma **URL**, como por exemplo, um link do youtube, utilizando a ferramenta **VideoView**, ou similares.

Realizei algumas pesquisas sobre isto, e consegui este código, porém não funcionou, sempre recebo a mensagem de que não foi possível executar o vídeo.

Já dei permissão e chequei a conexão com a internet e está tudo ok, testei o APP tanto no emulador, quanto no celular.

Se alguém puder me ajudar com isto ficarei muito grato!

Meu código:

```
public void playVideo()
            {
                try
                {
                    string url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lkBFpyo1Mc";
                    nvidCamera.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
                    nvidCamera.RequestFocus();
                    nvidCamera.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    alertShow("Ocorreu um problema: " + ex, false);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como, o youtube fornece a própria API, eles nunca irão fornecer a URL real do video do Youtube, isso por que violaria vários conceitos legais, assim como o direito dos proprietários, fora que ainda tem os videos de propagandas que são o maneira deles ganharem dinheiro através deste serviço que é gratuito para nós.

Eis o download do Youtube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

E alguns exemplos no github/youtube prontos: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples

Todavia eu não sei como usar isto no Xamarim, então uma solução alternativa seria usar um webView + url de embarcado do youtube, algo como:

```
var youtubePlayer = new WebView {
      Source = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID_VIDEO"
};
```

Mais detalhes em https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/

Por favor se tiver alguma duvida referente a isto comente